# GROUP_CONCAT() to fetch a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In this [Query/Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656677/6/0)

```
SELECT a.name, b.bgs 
FROM names a 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT rbg.a_id, GROUP_CONCAT(bg.bg, rbg.cl SEPARATOR ',') AS bgs 
        FROM bgs_names rbg 
        INNER JOIN bgs bg ON bg.id = rbg.bg_id 
        GROUP BY rbg.a_id
    ) b ON b.a_id = a.id 
WHERE a.id = 1
//name: studio
//bgs : blackcolour,redcolour,bluecolour,bluergba
```

I want to get the **values** of `bgs` as a valid `Array` like this

```
Array
(
    ['colour'] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'black'
            [1] => 'red'
            [2] => 'blue'
        )

    ['rgba'] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'blue'
        )

)
```

How to handle that in `SQL` to `explode()` it?

What I do using PHP is making another separator between `bg.bg, rbg.cl` like this `GROUP_CONCAT(bg.bg,':',rbg.cl SEPARATOR ',') AS bgs`

which fetches `black:colour,red:colour,blue:colour,blue:rgba`

Then I do the following

```
<?php
$string = "black:colour,red:colour,blue:colour,blue:rgba";
$array = explode(',', $string);
echo "<br>";
$newarr = null;
$lastarr = [];
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $newarr = explode(':', $arr);
    $lastarr[$newarr[1]][] = $newarr[0];
}
print_r($lastarr);
?>
```

Which gives me my intended result, Can I do it using `SQL` to make a single `explode()` or a faster method to deal with `$string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group the `child_value`s by the `parent_key`, so instead of `group_concat`ing the whole thing, group on `parent_key` and concat the `child_key` like this

```
SELECT 
  `parent_key`, GROUP_CONCAT(`child_value` SEPARATOR ',') AS array 
FROM 
  `table`
GROUP BY `parent_key`;
```

Returns:

```
parent_key  array              
----------  -------------------
a           The earth          
b           The moon,The rift  
c           The sun
```

Then use php to explode each value of `array` on commas.

Comment: Updated the Query.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using PDO, you could use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` without using `GROUP_CONCAT()` at all.

Comment: Sadly, I have to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` Since I fetch other columns with `LIMIT 1` with it, It is not the actual full-query I use, But the part I have a problem with, Will add this now to my Question, Also Yes, I use `PDO`

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do in plain SQL, although it looks like you could do something with MySQL's JSON data type, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Updated the Query.